# SMTP mailer is not working in codeignitor 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp, codeigniter-3

> Failed to authenticate password. Error: 535 Incorrect authentication
>   data  Unable to send email u`enter code here`sing PHP SMTP. Your
>   server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

```
$config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'mail.******.com',
  'smtp_port' => 587,
  'smtp_user' => 'tracker@******.com', 
  'smtp_pass' => '7Wj{S******KU{', 
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

$message = 'Hiii';

       $this->load->library('email', $config);
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        // $this->load->library('email');
      $this->email->from('tracker@******.com'); // change it to yours

      $this->email->to($usremail);// change it to yours 

      $this->email->cc('');
      // $this->email->bcc('gobinath@******.com');
      $this->email->subject('hi');

      $this->email->message($message);

      $mailsucc = $this->email->send();
    if ($mailsucc) {
        echo "suc";
    exit();
    }else{
    $de = $this->email->print_debugger();
    print_r($de);
    exit();
    }
```

Comment: Your question needs server revision  to have a good answer but a general advice from experience with similar situations you should check ports may be firewall blocked your request and if it still got error in log so I suggest to use SSMTP as smtp messenger it's very lightweight and extremely fast also better than other apps .

Comment: Try changing the port from TLS TO SSL and please make sure you have entered correct credentials

Comment: Me too facing same issue from so many days with SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for a while, and finally I get it. I hope this works for you too.

1. Define your timezone:
    
   [php timezone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
2. Set up your email account to allow IMAP access, and allow email to be used in less secure applications
   [less secure apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-419)
   [IMAP Access](https://support.google.com/a/answer/105694?hl=en)
3. Set up your mail server with codeigniter: 

   `$this->load->library('email');
   $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
   $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
   $config['smtp_user'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com';
   $config['smtp_pass'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
   $config['smtp_port'] = 465;     (465/587)
   $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
   $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
   $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl'; (SSL/TSL)
   $this->email->initialize($config);
   $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");`
4. Prepare your mail to send: 

   `$this->email->from('xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'ANY-NAME');
   $this->email->to('yyyy@yyy.yyy');
   $this->email->subject('Email Test');
   $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');
   if($this->email->send()){
        echo "sent";
   }
   else{
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
   }`

Comment: remember to port 465 works with SSL encrypt and 587 port with TSL encrypt